# Piwik Sum Pageviews and Searches

Tags: matomo

For my website the (internal) searches count on my website (mainly a specialized search engine) just as normal pageviews. Piwik however counts them separately. How can I tell piwik to sum both counts?

**Update 1**
After the answer from John Cave, I manually counted the actions in "detailed visitor log" on today:
* 42 "normal" page views (without icon)
* 22 outlinks (with the outlink icon)
* 22 site search (with the loupe icon)

In the "visits over time" chart I hovered over today and got that figures:
* 42 Pageviews
* 22 Outlinks
* 16 Searches

Interesting is also the difference between 22 Searches in "detailed visitor log" and 16 Searches in "visits over time". When I looked closer in the "detailed visitor log", I found, that 3 searches were executed twice. Seems those doesn't count at all.

**Update 2**
I asked the question in Piwik-Issuetracker now: https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/7136

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure searches are not counted twice? Once by the page view counter, once by the site search system? For my site, Piwik definitely doesn't count everything starting with /search.php any differently to a page view, aside from it recording the search terms.